# Error "Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow."

Tags: vb.net, oracle

I'm tasked to create a program that will run an extremely long query. That query executes well in Oracle but whenever I try to run it from VB.Net, it results to the error mentioned on the title. And also, I have noticed that when I copy my query to an SQLDataSource, it copied only certain parts and not the whole query. Is there any chance for this? Thank you!

Comment: The problem is clearly in VB.net and not Oracle, so you will need to provide more details about your VB set-up - versions, IDE, libraries, etc.

Comment: How do you want us to see what is wrong when you did not provide any code either from DB or VB.Net?